# Converting video on client-side with javascript

Tags: javascript, video, web, video-conversion

Is there a way to convert video, using javascript and a browser, on a client-side.

I'm looking for solutions that minimize our server's process and show progress of the conversion.

If there isn't such a way, how do i show process of a video conversion?

Comment: Convert video? Convert video to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple and standart way to do it (its not impossible anyway, you could use some
components, but certian for a big public, they will recuse for security risks).

For know how you show the progress of the video conversion, you need to say what tools you are using in the server to convert the video.

Comment: Yeah i guessed that you need to know which tools, I didn't want to post two questions in one post...